# Reenable hidden package suggestions from GHC

Tags: ghc

Previously, GHC would inform me when I tried to import a module from an installed, but hidden, package:

```
Could not find module 'Foo'
It is a member of the hidden package 'foo-0.1.0.0'.
Perhaps you need to add 'foo' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
```

Now<sup>1</sup>, it doesn't:

```
Could not find module 'Foo'
Perhaps you meant Bar (from bar-0.1.0.0)
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Has this feature been removed, or is it simply off by default (and if so, how can I enable it)?

---

<sup>1</sup> I suspect this came with the version bump to 8.0.0, though I'm not positive.